# C# connecting to Dear System API and getting SaleList

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, system.net.httpwebrequest

When I tried to get list of Sales from Dear Systems, I've got an error response of 500 Internal Server Error.
I have this following codes.

```
            string xmlStringResult = string.Empty;
            string url = _cred.StoreName + "/SaleList";
            try
            {
                var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.ContentType = "application/xml";
                req.Headers.Add("api-auth-accountid", _cred.AccountId);
                req.Headers.Add("api-auth-applicationkey", _cred.APIKey);
                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        string message = String.Format("Call failed. Received HTTP {0}", resp.StatusCode);
                        AppendLog(string.Format("Error: {0}", message));
                        return xmlStringResult;
                    }

                    var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                    xmlStringResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendLog(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
            return xmlStringResult;
```

Please advice and Thank you.

Comment: Can you debug this and see what the resp.StatusDescription says?

Comment: An unexpected error occured.

Comment: Constructing this query in a debugging tool like fiddler or postman will help you identify if there is a problem with the Dear Systems server or your code itself. If the debug tool performs correctly, there could be a problem with the url that is being created.

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming the error was truly the response from the Dear Systems (not error caught in your catch block) :

Do you have control over the Dear Systems?

- If so, I'd check from the server which hosts the Dear Systems,
  Internal Server Errors are usually logged in the Event Viewer (**Start** > Type '**Event Viewer**').
- If not, you should ask for help from those who has control over the
  system to check it for you.

Comment: I have tried using Postman and it is working fine. I've got the Sales List

Comment: Try to monitor your HTTP Request & Response using fiddler, it will catch every HTTP request on your machine. Open fiddler, use both postman and your compiled code to do the HTTP Request, then compare what's the difference of the HTTP Request(s) between the two in fiddler.